# How to completely copy one iframe to another iframe with both html and css? CSS not activating

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have 2 iframes on top of each other, 1st is foreground, that user interacts with, and 2nd is background, that is visible only while 1st one is loading. 2nd is unclickable and also the same as 1st, it's there just to fix blinking while the main iframe is loading. My code:

**testing here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_script**

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
iframe.invisible {
    display: none;
}
iframe.unclickable {
    pointer-events: none;
}
</style>

<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#iframeID1').on('load', function()
    {
        $('#iframeID1').contents().find('a[href!="javascript:void(0)"]').filter('a[target!="_blank"]').filter('a[target!="_top"]').filter('a[target!="_parent"]').on('click', function()
        {
            $('#iframeID1').addClass('invisible');
            $('#iframeID2').removeClass('invisible');
        });
        $('#iframeID1').removeClass('invisible');
        $('#iframeID2').addClass('invisible');
        $('#iframeID2').contents().find('html').html($('#iframeID1').contents().find('html').html());

    });

});
</script>
</head>

<body>

<iframe id="iframeID1" height="800px" width="800px" seamless="seamless" scrolling="yes" src="https://www.w3schools.com/" frameborder="0" class="invisible"></iframe>
<iframe id="iframeID2" height="800px" width="800px" seamless="seamless" scrolling="yes" frameborder="0"class="invisible unclickable" ></iframe>
</body>

</html>
```

Right now, when I click any link on `iframeID1` (foreground), `iframeID2` becomes visible, however I see only pure html, no CSS. I think it's because I'm copying only html, how should I be copying css too?

Notice, that `iframeID2` does not have src. If I add the same src as `iframeID1`, it works for a while, until user navigates to different site.

Comment: @mplungjan ehm, what do you mean? I am swapping visibility right now. One is visible while another is invisible and vice versa, but problem is with css

Comment: You can edit that w3 content and link to it, but we'll never see your edit. Use jsfiddle.net or similar

Comment: Don't copy. Just show the iframe with real content when it is loaded

Comment: *"until user navigates to different site"* ... this is same issue I pointed out to you yesterday. You can't access a cross origin iframe...even if it starts on same origin. Once origin changes you are blocked by *"same origin policy"*

Comment: @charlietfl my bad, I meant different page that has a different css. This is not a cross origin issue, CSS just isn't copying to as good as HTML.

Comment: @mplungjan right now only `iframeID1` is loading pages, after loading finishes, loaded page is copied to `iframeID2`. I have to do it like that. But the problem is that CSS doesn't get copied somewhy

Comment: as far as css if there are relative paths used in link tags they might not be correct path where you are putting them. Whatever your use case is this looks like a really poor idea

Comment: @charlietfl would you be able to test on that URL and let me know how to fix this? You sound smart, but I got no clue myself due to coding web for only 1 day now.

Comment: Why do you have to do it like that? Just show the loaded page??!!!

Comment: it god damn blinks! I'm hiding a few elements, but for the sake of simplicity removed that. If I don't do it like that, then user can see those elements for a few ms - bad thing.

Comment: Fade it in......

Comment: What is your higher level objective? Using this sort of UI with same domain iframes is very uncommon

Comment: @mplungjan How about when user clicks inner-page on iframe? I would have to hide the iframe and fade-in again after it's loaded, which would make my real website's background visible for a few ms, aka another full-screen blinking. I'm sure this is a good solution, it's just that CSS isn't getting loaded into `iframeID2`. I have to make this iframe look as natural as possible, just like a real website. Real website doesn't show you white screen while it's loading an inner page (2nd) - you see previous page until inner one is loaded

Comment: Why are you trying to copy html from one to another in the first place? The one you move the content to has already `loaded` so there are no events available to know when css files and images etc load with he modified html. Again this really doesn't seem in any way practical

Comment: I'm copying html from `iframeID1` to `iframeID2`, so that when user clicks any link on `iframeID1`, I will temporarily (until `iframeID1` loads) show him `iframeID2`, which will be the exact previous page he was on, so that he doesn't have to stare into a white empty unnatural looking screen for a few seconds

Comment: Just copy the url over to the `src` instead